# How to filter out rows on one sheet based on cell values listed in another sheet in google app scripts GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

My original post has an answer from @The Master but i needed a little more details so I am editing it. I hope @The Master or someone can help.

In google app scripts, I have a script to filter for rows that has a certain transaction users (such as DEOK645, JETH850, JOON409, etc...) and that dispense quantity is greater than 0. Please see the script below. My question is, instead of listing the values of DEOK645, JETH850, etc... in the script itself, is there a way to specify these values based on a list in another sheet? For example, I will list these users on separate rows in a sheet call "Personnel" so instead of updating the code every time I have a need to add or change, I can just go to the sheet "Personnel" and add or delete values in the sheet. My goal is to have both the filtered set of data ("filteredValue) and one that exclude the filtered set of data (noFilteredValue). If I can get some suggestions, I would appreciate it! Thanks for your time!

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('V1');
  var firstRow = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var C1 = firstRow[0].indexOf('TxnUser');
  var C2 = firstRow[0].indexOf('DispensedQuantity');
  var rangeVals = 
  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  var filteredRange = rangeVals.reduce(function(obj, val){
    if ((val[C1] === "DEOK645"|| val[C1] === "JETH850" || val[C1] === "JOON409"|| val[C1] === "THAM1452") && val[C2] > 0) {
    obj.filteredValue.push(val);
    } else { obj.noFilteredValue.push(val);}
  return obj;
  }, {filteredValue: [], noFilteredValue: []});
   // The above code works

   //I tried to adapt the solution from @The Master but it says "Set" is not defined but maybe that is simply due to my lack of proficiency. Here is what I have tried:
  
  var Personnel = ss.getSheetByName('Personnel');
  var PersonnelSet = new Set(Personnel.getDataRange().getValues().flat());
  var filteredRange = rangeVals.reduce(function(obj,val){
    if (!PersonnelSet.has(val)) {obj.filteredValue.push(val);
    } else {obj.noFilteredValue.push(val);}
    return obj;
  }, {filteredValue: [], noFilteredValue: []});
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Are you on v8? The below code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: @TheMaster, it was the V8 that caused the trouble.

Comment: @TheMaster, thank you very much! Regarding the 'excludeSet = new Set(excludeSheet.getDataRange().getValues().flat());', how would one adjust this to  grab values from a specific column only rather than all cells in that sheet where 1st row is a header in the sheet? For example, the list for excludeSheet is located on column #3, with a header "Charge".

Comment: How did you get a specific range of `rangeVals`?

Comment: @TheMaster, I tried 'var Set1 = new Set(SpecSheet.getRange(2,4,SpecSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat());' to specify data beginning on row 2 of column D to the last of row of column D. Is this correct? I tried Logger.log(Set1) and console.log(Set1) but the result is {}; so I can't verify if the code is doing what I intended for it to do. The weird thing is I tried to log 'Set1 = new Set(SpecSheet.getDataRange().getValues().flat());' which i know produced intended result if it only contains the entries I want to exclude, the log still shows {}. Is there something I miss here?!

Comment: You can easily convert to array to log: `console.log([...Set1])`. The third parameter of getRange is "number of rows" and not the last row.

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for pointing out the number of rows, i need to subtract 1 from getLastRow() in order to get the actual "number of rows", correct? Also,  what do you mean by [...Set1]? My purpose is to get the items in Set1 listed. can you please type it out what the actual code to log the content of Set1 is? I tried console.log([...Set1]) and the error says SpecSheet is not iterable.

Comment: Correct. How did you define `Set1`?

Comment: @TheMaster, var SpecSheet = ss.getSheetByName('SpecSheet');
  var Set1 = new Set(SpecSheet.getRange(2,4,SpecSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().flat());

Comment: Then it should work: `console.log([...Set1])`. If it says `SpecSheet is not iterable.`, then Set1 is not a ``set`` but a ``sheet``. Make sure you haven't made a typo.

Comment: @TheMaster, it does work. Thank you. I do wonder what [...] means? console.log([...Set1]) result is [ 'MDACS', '' ], which tells contains 2 members, 'MDACS' and '', aka MDACS and empty. But as I define var Set1 = new Set(SpecSheet.getRange(2,4,SpecSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().flat()); which should take values from row 2 column 4 to the last row, which in this case is only 'MDACS', without the 'empty' ''. Another weird thing is getLastRow()-2, return exact same. Anyway, I can remove '' by Set1.delete('') and it will be correct, but I would like understand what really is going on here.

Comment: Better to ask a new question with [mcve]. `...` is spread operator. It is also mentioned in the Sets link I provided  below

Comment: @TheMaster, thank you. I found the reason to the question above. Sorry, I missed that part about the spread operator. I thought I Ctrl+F for the '...'  on the Sets page but I obviously did not do it right. Thanks for your great solution.

Comment: What's the reason ?

Comment: The reason is .getLastRow()-1 gives me 9, which is the last Row of the 1st Column (which happens to be the column with the most number of rows of data. In my mind, I was thinking that .getLastRow() would give me the last row of column 4, which would only be 2-1(header)=1 (rather than 9). Because of this, Set1 take the empty rows in column 4, which is ''. Speaking of which, is there a way to get only the number of rows of a specific column in a sheet?

Comment: [Top voted third and tenth Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script?sort=votes) and [third FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script?sort=frequent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
const rangeVals = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
const excludeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Personnel');
const excludeSet = new Set(excludeSheet.getDataRange().getValues().flat());
const filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(row){
    return !excludeSet.has(row[C1])  && row[C2]>0
});
```

Comment: I modified my question. I tried your suggestion but google App scripts says 'Set' is not defined. Any chance you can look at it again for me?

Comment: @ThienPham you should [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: @lamblichus, I enabled it, and with the modified work TheMaster, it is working!